# Opening a SharePoint file using a hyperlink

Tags: excel, content-editor-web-part, hyperlink, file

On a browser-based SharePoint drive, the default file-opening functionality for an macro-enabled Excel file is to open it directly in Excel; no asking for Open/Save As, no intermediary steps; when the file name is clicked in my SharePoint directory in the browser, it just opens in Excel.

Is there any way to duplicate this same functionality through a hyperlink on a SharePoint page to the same file? I created a button that links directly to the file using a relative path. Upon clicking the button, it prompts for Open/Save As (which isn't *that* big of a deal) but then the opened Excel file behaves differently than the same file if opened directly through the SharePoint directory in the browser.

How can I make this button open the file smoothly?

Comment: which type of file do you use ? Is it only Office docs or you have other file types ? I'm asking because the hyperlink url is different from one type to another.

Comment: It's a macro-enabled Excel file: `.xlsm`.